# You want to give $15$mg of Isuprel and you have a $1:100$ solution on hand. How many ml will you give to meet this order?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> You want to give $15$mg of Isuprel and you have a $1:100$ solution on hand. How many ml will you give to meet this order?

What I understood was the amount to be given is $15$ mg and the solution has $1$mg of it in $100$ mL.

So the required amount of liquid is = $100 \times 15 = 1500$mL.

But my answer is wrong. Where Did I miss?

**Edit :** I wrote $1$ gram instead of $1$ mg at first and one comment is about that.

Comment: There is $1500$ ml of solution (e.g., water) for $15$ ml of Isuprel, so the total amount to give would be $1500 + 15 = 1515$ ml for $15$ ml of Isuprel. However, for that to be the actual total for $15$ grams assumes the density of Isuprel is $1$ gm/ml, which may not be the case (I offhand have no idea what Isuprel is, much less what its density is). Overall, I believe this is a poor question.

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: The problem is unclear about the units that the $1:100$ ratio involves.  However if you say the solution has 1 gram of Isuprel per 100ml, then clearly 1500ml of solution will have 15 grams, not 15 mg of Isuprel.

Comment: @hardmath yes the inconsistency of the units in the ratio was troubling me as it wasn't said that what $1:100$ means. Is it $1$gram in $100$ml or $1$mg in $100$ml.